# <xsl:for-each> table

Tags: xslt, foreach, html-table

I try to output this 2 recipes in a table but I can't, it's shows me only first. How can I output both recipes in a table

this is my xml:

```
<region id="southwest">
        <name>Southwest</name>
        <recipe id="1" author="" kitchen="en" origin="en">  
            <title>Chicken Fiesta Salad</title>
            <type>main</type>
            <difficulty>middle</difficulty>
            <time>90 min.</time>
            <portions>8</portions>
        </recipe>
        <recipe id="2" author="" kitchen="en" origin="en">  
            <title>Cupcakes</title>
            <type>dessert</type>
            <difficulty>hard</difficulty>
            <time>60 min.</time>
            <portions>8</portions>
        </recipe>       
    </region>
```

ant this is my xsl:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Region</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Difficulty</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Portions</th>
    </tr>
<xsl:for-each select="region">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="recipe/title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="recipe/type"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="recipe/difficulty"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="recipe/time"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="recipe/portions"/></td>
      </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: It looks to me that you want to select the `recipe` in your `xsl:for-each` instead of the `region`.

Comment: @romanofski - Actually, I think he needs a `xsl:for-each` for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `for-each` over the recipe elements rather than the region elements

```
<xsl:for-each select="region/recipe">
```

And adjust your xpath expressions appropriately, e.g.

```
  <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="../name"/></td>
```